# Excel sum column's value of matching cell criteria for all the cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to sum Amount for all the dates if there is value in India row:
I tried implementing with `COUNTIF` function but its not solving my problem, any suggestion welcome, I am pretty new to Excel formulas.

[image]

Comment: Is your problem solved already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

Let's assume the top left cell on your image is cell "A1". Go to cell "C6" and paste the following formula:

```
=IF(C2>0,C2*(SUM(C4:C5)),"")
```

Now fill/copy that formula across to cell "G6". Then go to cell "H6" and paste the following formula:

```
=SUM(C6:G6)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: As 0*anything = 0, one can simplify to =C2*(SUM(C4:C5)). And if "Qty" is always 1 or 0 (i.e. it's a flag rather than a quantity) one could also do '=IF(C2>0,SUM(C3:C5),"")

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C2:E2+C3:E3,C4:E4+C5:E5)
```

It's basically adding the two first rows, adding third and fourth rows, and taking the sumproduct. Obviously, you need to make sure not have a number in both rows one and two, and in both rows three and four.